# mysql sum union results

Tags: sql, sum, union

See below sample. If id, A, B, D are the same with other records, then union and sum column "C"
.

```
my data:
id A  B  C  D
---------------------------
1  1  2  3  4
2  aa bb 10 dd
3  1  2  3  4
4  1  2  3  4
2  aa bb 30 dd

how to do after like below result:
id A  B  C  D
---------------------------
1  1  2  3  4
2  aa bb 40 dd    <----if id,A,B,D are same with other records,then union and sum column "C"
3  1  2  3  4
4  1  2  3  4

I tried to union all records,but fail and show"
id A  B  C  D
---------------------------
2  aa bb 49 dd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `GROUP BY ID, A, B, D` with `SUM(C)` like this:

```
SELECT id, A,  B,  SUM(C) AS C,  D
FROM Tablename
GROUP BY ID, A, B, D;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdb54/1)

Comment: I think there's only one table and he uses the word "union" the wrong way, but your answer is correct, but no need for subquery.